# PayPal does not return me my information

Tags: servlets, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using following paypal return value

http://localhost:8080/projectName/sucess?id=1

but when transaction completes it does not return me value of id

it return only http://localhost:8080/projectName/sucess

we have call sucess servlet after paypal transaction completes

Please help me

Comment: You might want to edit the question title, and add a 'not' :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pathinfo instead.

So http://localhost:8080/projectName/sucess/1 instead of http://localhost:8080/projectName/sucess?id=1

You can grab the `1` in servlet by `request.getPathInfo().substring(1)`.